# How to import data table of a Google Chart in R?

Tags: r

I try to figure out how to read data table of Google Chart in R.

For example the source code of [this page](http://alt19.com/19R/chart_showing_btc.php?shw=1&label=PPC_BTC&source=cryptsy&period=1day) contains historical Peercoin daily prices. I would like to copy in a R matrix the content of the data table that begin at line 497 with :

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Period', right_title_name],
        ['2014/10/01 18:00',  0.01189974],
        ['2014/10/02 18:00',  0.01194000],
        ['2014/10/03 18:00',  0.01171897],
        ['2014/10/04 18:00',  0.01199999],
        ['2014/10/05 18:00',  0.01200000],
        ['2014/10/06 18:00',  0.01188685],
        ['2014/10/07 18:00',  0.01161999],

        // data here

        ]);
```

I've installed several packages like `RCurl`, `XML` and `data.table` and follow examples from related questions (i.e. using `fread`, `readHTMLTable` and `getURL`) but I'm facing different issues to read the correct data from the source code. Too much noise I can't filter out. For example with `RCurl` :

```
library(RCurl)
address <- "http://alt19.com/19R/chart_showing_btc.php?shw=1&label=LTC_BTC&source=cryptsy&period=1day"
data <- getURL(address)
```

`data` has all the data but I'm not able to select date and prices with `strsplit(data, "some code here")`.

May somebody suggest me a idea to achieve this ?

Thank you,
Florent

Comment: Kindly post the issues which you are facing OR can you please post your code so that we get to know your effort in solving the problem. Regards.

Comment: Hello, I've updated the question with a try using RCurl. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there's a better way but what I usually do after getting the page source with getURL, as you posted, is to use some string manipulations.
My try:

```
pageSource <- getURL(address)    
index1<-str_locate(pageSource,"'Period', right_title_name],")[[2]]
sourceCut1<-substr(pageSource,index1+1,nchar(pageSource))
index2<-str_locate(sourceCut1,"]);")[[1]]
sourceCut2<-substr(sourceCut1,1,index2-1)
#sourceCut2 is the part of page source with the data
data<-str_trim(strsplit(sourceCut2,"\n")[[1]]) #split data rows
dates<-gsub("^.*'([0-9/: ]+).*$", "\\1", data) #extract dates
dates<-as.POSIXct(dates,format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
values<-as.numeric(gsub("^.*,([0-9 .]+).*$", "\\1", data)) #extract numeric values
mydata<-data.frame(dates=dates,values=values)
```

Note that it will continue working only if the structure of the data (date format, blank spaces, square brackets) remains unchanged, otherwise you will probably need to modify some of the regex.

Comment: Thank you cosmocin. I added a double anti-slash before the `)` in the `str_locate` because it returns an error saying "Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern". I also use `na.omit` when making `values` and `dates` then it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is highly specific to your situation (and that URL) but it may be enough of a base for others with similar challenges. You can use the `V8` package to parse & interpret javascript, so I grab the page, extract the javascript for the table, do some cleanup of it so it can be interpreted pretty easily then post-process the conversion. It's not pretty and others might be able to optimize it, but it will get you what you need:

```
library(V8)
library(httr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

pg <- GET("http://alt19.com/19R/chart_showing_btc.php?shw=1&label=LTC_BTC&source=cryptsy&period=1day")

content(pg, as="text") %>% 
  str_extract("(google\\.visualization\\.arrayToDataTable.*\\]\\);)") %>% 
  str_replace("google\\.visualization\\.arrayToDataTable\\(", "[") %>% 
  str_replace("\\)", "]") %>% 
  str_replace("right_title_name", "'right_title_name'") -> tbl

ct <- new_context()
ct$eval(tbl) %>% 
  str_split(",") %>% 
  extract2(1) %>% 
  matrix(ncol=2, byrow=TRUE) %>% 
  data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>% 
  tail(-1) %>% 
  select(timestamp=1, value=2) %>% 
  mutate(timestamp=as.Date(as.POSIXct(timestamp)),
         value=as.numeric(value)) -> dat

glimpse(dat)

## Observations: 227
## Variables:
## $ timestamp (date) 2014-10-01, 2014-10-02, 2014-10-03, 2014-1...
## $ value     (dbl) 0.01189974, 0.01194000, 0.01171897, 0.01199...

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(timestamp, value)) + geom_line(size=0.5) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. For some reason `tbl` returns `[1] NA` and it looks like it is caused by `str_extract`. I've seen in the documentation that usage for this command must be `str_extract(string, pattern)` but I cannot see comma in the code. Not sure it is the problem as I don't fully understand the meaning of `*\\]\\);)` in the process of extraction. I only guess you try to extract date and price after string `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable`.